# Integrating C++ code with any web technology on Linux

Tags: python, c++

i am writing an program in c++ and i need an web interface to control the program and which will be efficient and best programming language ...

Comment: it an web crawler ..i use ubuntu

Comment: @mama: Please **Update** your question with information.  Do not add comments.  Please edit your question to contain all the information.

Answer (score 1):

Your application will just have to listen to messages from the network that your web application would send to it.

Any web application (whatever the language) implementation could use sockets so don't worry about the details, just make sure your application manage messages that you made a protocol for.

Now, if you want to keep it all C++, you could use CPPCMS for your web application.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a framework like [Thrift](http://incubator.apache.org/thrift/) to communicate between a PHP/Python/Ruby/whatever webapp and a C++ daemon, or you could even go the extra mile (probably harder than just using something like Thrift) and write language bindings for the scripting language of your choice.

Either of the two options gives you the ability to write web-facing code in a language more suitable for the task while keeping the "heavy lifting" in C++.

Answer (score -1):

If it were Windows, I could advice you to register some COM component for your program. At least from ASP.NET it is easily accessible.

You could try some in-memory exchange techniques like reading/writing over a localhost socket connection. It however requires you to design some exchange protocol first.

Or data exchange via a database. You program writes/reads data from the database, the web front-end reads/writes data to the database.

Comment: ohh but i am interested in linux only

Answer (score -1):

The Win32 API method.

MSDN - Getting Started with Winsock:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738545%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

(Since you didn't specify an OS, we're assuming Windows)

Comment: I notice I'm getting -1 because I mentioned Win32. Just so you're all aware, he didn't specify OS in his original post. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

This is not as simple as it seems!

There is a mis-match between your C++ program (which presumibly is long running otherwise why would it need controlling) and a typical web program which starts up when it receives the http request and dies once the reply is sent.

You could possibly use one of the Java based web servers where it is possible to have a long running task.

Alternatively you could use a database or other storage as the communication medium:-
 You program periodically writes it current status to a well know table, when a user invokes the control application it reads the current status and gives an appropriate set of options to the user which can then be stored in the DB, and actioned by your program the next time it polls for a request.

This works better if you have a queuing mechanism avaiable, as it can then be event driven rather than polled.

Answer (score -1):

Go PHP :) Look at this [Program execution Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.exec.php)

Answer (score -1):

Did you take a look at [Wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/)? It's a widget-centric C++ framework for web applications, has a solid MVC system, an ORM, ...